# Cannot enable prefab: "No variants found for ':app'" error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm following this official Google doc: https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/oboe/update-build-settings

It says: "Enable the `prefab` option in the `buildFeatures` section". My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    ndkVersion "23.1.7779620"

    buildFeatures {
        prefab true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.test"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                ...
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }

        debug {
            ...
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: after adding the `buildFeatures {  prefab true }` section, I get the following error when running Gradle sync. I did not make any more changes, just remove this section and it builds again, but I need to enable prefabs for a specific AAR dependency that uses this feature.

> No variants found for ':app'

What's the problem and how to enable the `prefab` feature in an Android Gradle project?

I use the latest Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2, Gradle 7.4, Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2

Comment: what is your gradle version  and gradle plugin version?

Comment: @ArdaKazancı: Gradle 7.4, Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.2

Answer (score -1):

Your problem could be just a gradle version issue. You seem to be using an old version of the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin). Try upgrading it from 4.2.2 to 7.2.2.

If the AAR you're integrating into your app is Oboe, I followed the same steps [you mentioned](https://developer.android.com/games/sdk/oboe/update-build-settings) to add it into my project. I was able to build the project successfully and use Oboe in my .cpp files.

My environment config:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Gradle version : 7.3.3
AGP : 7.2.2
kotlin : 1.7.10
```

Here's my app's `build.gradle` :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    buildFeatures {
        prefab true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.oboetester"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags '-std=c++17'
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.18.1'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/']
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.13.0'

    implementation 'com.google.oboe:oboe:1.5.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

project level `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

You can also refer [this sample project](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/prefab/prefab-dependency) by Google

Comment: I'm targeting a pretty old Android version. Yes, it did occur to me that upgrading Gradle might fix it, but I want to fix it for my configuration. AGP 4.2.2 is higher than required for `prefab`, that's 4.0 or 4.1, but I can't find a link right now that states this (odd, I found it easily two weeks ago and verified that my config should work).